# Export all the different tables from a database (AdventureWorks2019) into CSV format as table name in same path

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

This code is for one table to export into CSV format from a database at a time.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-0LA566U\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=AdventureWorksDW2019;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('''
                                select * from DimAccount'''
                              ,conn)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\cdtpr\OneDrive\Desktop\connections\DimAccount.csv', index = False)
```

As above code is for one table to export into CSV format at a time. For example I have exported DimAccount. So I am able to export one table at time but how can I export all 30 tables at a time as table name.
I want to export all the 30 tables from AdventureWorks2019 database as table name into CSV format. Please help me that how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get all tables' names with this query:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

then write a for loop and replace the table name in your this code

```py
for table in tables:
    sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('''select * from {table}''',conn)
  
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
    df.to_csv (f'C:\Users\cdtpr\OneDrive\Desktop\connections\{table}.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Hey, just a heads up that [`sys.tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is a more reliable / better view for getting a list of all tables. The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` only exists to be ANSI-compliant, but isn't really maintained as well.

Comment: Now I am getting error like
Syntax error: (unicode error) Unicode escape code bites in position 2 3 truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape